Kotlin Gradle Plugin Version Issue in Flutter Project After Adding Firebase
I am working on a Flutter project and have encountered an error indicating that my project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Despite following various steps to update the Kotlin and Gradle versions, the error persists. This issue specifically arises after adding Firebase dependencies to my project. I am using VS Code for development. Below are the steps I have taken so far:

Updated ext.kotlin_version in android/build.gradle:
Updated Kotlin version in android/app/build.gradle:
Updated gradle-wrapper.properties:
Executed the following commands:

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk
flutter upgrade



This is the error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             50.2s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                                                   │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update /Users/rohitnarwal/Documents/healthy_whisker_app/android/build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                                                                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Root level build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

App level build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.hw.healthy_whisker_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.hw.healthy_whisker_app"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
  // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.0')
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}


Does this answer your question?

no, I have tried multiple versions from 2.0.0 - 1.9 etc etc

worked specifically using version number 1.9.24
